# SPARQL query - multiple OPTIONALS

Tags: sparql, option-type

I want to retrieve the entities of the classes along with some information - if exists (e.g. label, comment, image)

I run the following query:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?entity ?label ?comment ?image      
WHERE {
  ?entity a ?class .
OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:label ?label } .
OPTIONAL {?entity schema:image ?image} .
OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:comment ?comment} .
OPTIONAL {?entity rdfs:label ?label} .
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?comment), "EN") && langMatches(lang(?label), "EN")) .
}
```

Although, some triples contain this extra information I do not receive them
(even if I re-write and include all the optional statements in one statement)

How could I compose such a query?

Comment: the query is correct, what exactly doesn't work on which data and with which triple store?

Comment: It is a "synthetic" data set I have created for test purposes. The weird is if I use only one optional statement I retrieve results.
What I try to do is to retrieve along with the entities, their label, comment and image if and only if exist.

Comment: each OPTIONAL is a left-join, so it can be complex - but in the end you should get the complete result. Which triple store do you use?

Comment: I created the triples of my dataset in protege' and I have uploaded them on virtuoso where I run/test my queries.

Comment: Eventually, I solved the problem. I had to put the filter statement inside the optional statements that refer to the comment and the label. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ah yes, of course - if there is no  such label or comment at all, the whole result would be filtered out because indeed unbound variables do not have any lang tag